# Vector normal and direction

Tags: java, vector

I don't know much about vectors nor algebra and was wondering if the normal of a vector or the dot product is the same as the direction of the same.

I'm writting code and I have this to normalize the vectors:

```
public Point2D.Double normalizeVectors(Point2D.Double vectorA, Point2D.Double vectorB) {

    double auxX = 0, auxY = 0;
    if ((vectorA.x != 0 || vectorA.y != 0) && (vectorB.x != 0 || vectorB.y != 0)) {

        auxX = vectorB.x - vectorA.x;
        auxY = vectorB.y - vectorA.y;
        double nv = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(auxX, 2) + Math.pow(auxY, 2));

        auxX = auxX == 0 ? 0 : auxX / nv;
        auxY = auxY == 0 ? 0 : auxY / nv;
    }
    return new Point2D.Double(auxX, auxY);
}
```

I don't know if that works for both things, is only dot product but not dir or I have it completely wrong.

If someone could explain me vectors and directions would be thankful.

Comment: What is that method supposed to do? For normalizing you only need one vector. Are you trying to subtract one vector from the other and normalize the result?

Comment: Normalizing a Vector is basically pointing to the same direction with a length of 1. This will not be the same as making the dot product of two vectors since the direction may change.

Comment: I'm using it to get an unity vector of the direction for two points. Although that's what I intended to do, and that's why I opened the post, I'm unsure if I'm mixing concepts

Comment: @gtgaxiola The dot product is different then? And normal and direcction are the same then?

Comment: Dot pruduct is just a number and it doesn't have a direction.

Comment: "explain me vectors and directions" is off-topic for Stackoverflow.

Comment: All solved, thank you!